# Why does my validation of timepan field with DisplayFormat annotation always fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a timespan annotated with a display format like so:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm\\:ss\\.fff}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
public TimeSpan QualifiedTime { get; set; }
```

I have this field on a form:

```
<label asp-for="LeagueDriver.QualifiedTime" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="LeagueDriver.QualifiedTime" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="LeagueDriver.QualifiedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Posting a value that fits the format, such as "01:23.123" always fails validation.

I'm totally confused why this is. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to provide the hours part as well - `00:01:23.123`

Comment: Is there a way around that? These will never have hours.

Comment: Not unless you were to create a custom ModelBinder for the property

Comment: It's going to be a much nicer client-side UX with a [javascript textbox mask](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/846537/Input-Masking-with-ASP-NET-MVC), hopefully that will enforce the same server-side validation and remove the error. By the way, what is the error?

Comment: Just the generic “invalid input for” validation error message.